# AnimatedVisibility with initiallyVisible deprecated

Tags: android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

AnimatedVisibility with initiallyVisible deprecated. How to achieve this animation with new api? Thanks in advance.

```
@Composable
fun DefaultTransition(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = true,
        enter = slideInVertically(
            initialOffsetY = { 50 }
        ) + fadeIn(initialAlpha = 0.3f),
        exit = slideOutVertically() + fadeOut(),
        content = content,
        initiallyVisible = false
    )
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer.

```
val visibleState = remember { MutableTransitionState(false) }
visibleState.targetState = true

AnimatedVisibility(visibleState,
  enter = slideInVertically(
  initialOffsetY = { 50 }
  ) + fadeIn(initialAlpha = 0.3f),
  exit = slideOutVertically() + fadeOut() {
    content()
}
```