# Why can't I use `AnimatedVisibility` in a `BoxScope`?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a layout which looks like this:

```
Row {
        ...

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .width(50.dp)
        ) {
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = isSelected && selectedAnimationFinished,
                enter = fadeIn(),
                exit = fadeOut()
            ) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

But I get the compile-time error:

```
fun RowScope.AnimatedVisibility(visible: Boolean, modifier: Modifier = ..., enter: EnterTransition = ..., exit: ExitTransition = ..., content: AnimatedVisibilityScope.() -> Unit): Unit' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary
```

It appears that Kotlin finds the `AnimatedVisibility` function ambiguous, since Compose exposes multiple `AnimatedVisibility` functions with the same signature: there's a `fun AnimatedVisibility` with no receiver, and a `fun RowScope.AnimatedVisibility` which requires `RowScope`.

From what I can gather, Kotlin is complaining about me using the `RowScope` version incorrectly, but I just want to use the version with no receiver!

Using `this.AnimatedVisibility` also doesn't help.

The only workaround I've found that works is to fully qualify the name, like `androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility(...)`. But I have no idea why this works.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Is there a better option I can use than fully qualifying the name?

Comment: Import it as a alias

Comment: Also tried importing as an alias, doesn't help

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Ok, you import the correct version as an alias, then, assuming you are using Android studio, when you type that name, the code completion tempts you, before hitting enter, just check in the right of the pop-up whether the imported alias is being suggested or the default AnimatedVisibility. I know sounds trivial, but an appreciably trapping step. Just check once

Comment: I agree mate, just doesn't makes sense. All the overloads have the same package and name, which means there is only 1 import for *all* the overloads (it looks like `androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility`). For this reason aliasing doesn't help - if I alias this import, I'm also aliasing all the other overloads at the same time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in the language - overload resolution is not aware of `@DslMarker`s and such stuff. I couldn't find related issues on Kotlin bugtracker so I filed one myself -  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48215.

Comment: That's absolutely wild, thank you very much for the info and for opening the bug issue!

Answer (score 48):

One workaround is to use a fully qualified name:

```
Box {
    androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility(visibile = ...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is 'Is there a better option I can use than fully qualifying the name?'

Answer (score 8):

Other workaround than the one Alex mentioned is referring to the Column Scope when you have the Box inside a Column:

```kotlin
this@Column.AnimatedVisibility(visible = condition) {
    Composable()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is creating new composable method and using it in a Row:

```
@Composable
fun AnimatedThings() {
    Box {
        AnimatedVisiblity(visible = ...) {
            ...
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, I used StateValue for the value of the AnimatedVisibility with a default value of true.
I found out that was fixed to me by giving the StateValue a default value of false and then using LaunchedEffect to change the value to true, or by clicking on any view on the screen that changes the value to true.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem  with AnimatedVisibility. I have a Column, then a Box, and then what I wanted to animate, which is wrapped in an `if` statement. But using `this@Column.AnimatedVisibility()` didn't change anything for me, and neither did explicitly using the fully qualified name.

@LukeNeedham I see that in your code you have `AnimatedVisibility(visible = isSelected && selectedAnimationFinished,...)`. I don't know how you're wanting to use that condition, but based off of this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67725533/animatedvisibility-with-initiallyvisible-deprecated?rq=3) on Stack Overflow, I wanted to share what worked for me!

I think you may be able to solve by declaring one of those conditions as `mutableStateOf()` and the other as `MutableTransitionState()`, then using whichever was the mutableStateOf as your conditional and the MutableTransitionState for the AnimatedVisibility.

```
@Composable
fun mySolution(){

val isSelected by remember {
    mutableStateOf(false)
}
val selectedAnimationFinished = remember { 
    MutableTransitionState(false) 
}
selectedAnimationFinished.targetState = true

Row {
    ...
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .width(50.dp)
    ) {
        if (isSelected) {
        this@Row.AnimatedVisibility(
            selectedAnimationFinished.currentState,
            enter = fadeIn(),
            exit = fadeOut()
        ) {
            ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and the Compose looks like this

```
Column {
   Text( fill max width )
}
```

I wanted to display an icon at the start of the Text when a mutableState toggles.

I thought it should be easy with the Box wrapping the Icon and Text

```
Column {
  Box {
    AnimatedVisibility (visibility = mutableState.value, enter = .., exit = ..) {
       Icon ()
    }

    Text()
  }

}
```

It did not work. I also used the

```
this@Column.AnimatedVisibility(visible = ...)
```

It worked but it did not honor the modifier and always the Icon() appears at the top left of the Column.

Finally I need to create a function which inputs the modifier, visibility, enter (optional), exit (optional) and content(). the final composable looks like this

```
@Composable
fun AnimateView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    visible: Boolean, // This comes from the mutableState<Boolean>
    enter: EnterTransition = fadeIn(),
    exit: ExitTransition = fadeOut(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        modifier = modifier,
        visible = visible,
        enter = enter,
        exit = exit
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

The preview of the same looks like this

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun AnimateViewPreview() {
    val visible = true
    Box {
        AnimateView(visible = visible) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Search,
                contentDescription = "notification icon",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterStart),
                tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error
            )
        }

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            text = "Stack Overflow Rocks!",
            textAlign = TextAlign.End
        )
    }
}
```

The final result:
[image: Preview Result]